# Session: Configured save path APPPATH.application/logs' is not writable by the PHP process in centos nginx

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, centos

I encounter the not writable by the PHP process in centos nginx. Previously it works and i already created the seesion path in my project and all set write permission. But the strange thing is it is not only in one project also encounter in other projects too.Is it need to change in php.ini ? I noticed all files not able to write in server anyone.Can anyone advise?

Thanks

[Audit Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9PBy.png)

[SELinux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzwQL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when testing CI4 recently.

What I did was locate the is_writable validation function in the core libraries, tested it in a separate script, passed it a file or path name and it tested true when ran as root, but from NGINX it was false.

So this pointed me towards SELinux and the permissions for the NGINX process itself.

1. Run: tail -f /var/log/audit.log
2. Call the URL from the browser
3. Watch log writings to permission related issues for the path in question

You may have to allow it in SELinux. Can't remember the config, but this should help get you started anyway.

Comment: Hi Karl,

Thank you for your help. 
I tried this way and it still cannot solve. In my SELinux, htppd_can_network_connect is already on. And i try to run  this command  $ setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs 
to enable nfs and it still off in my SELinux. Do you have any other guess ?

I just uploaded the screenshot for your reference.